# Sporadic test failures due to unknown error while taking screenshot in Chromedriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

We are starting to get sporadic test failures when running in *Chrome*. I would say this happens 3 out of every 10 tests runs. I have no idea why this is occurring or how to fix it. Any help is appreciated. Below is the stack trace error we see.

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot take screenshot
>   from unknown error: Failed to capture tab: unknown error
>   JavaScript stack:
>   Error: Failed to capture tab: unknown error
>       at checkForExtensionError (chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/background.js:14:17)
>       at Object.callback (chrome-extension://aapnijgdinlhnhlmodcfapnahmbfebeb/background.js:37:5)
>       at safeCallbackApply (extensions::sendRequest:21:15)
>       at handleResponse (extensions::sendRequest:73:7)
>     (Session info: chrome=42.0.2311.135)
>     (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 13 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf323ce037c5f92db6c1bba601c2ac43ad8', time: '2014-10-23 13:11:40'
>   System info: host: 'RTCITS5CG2XY1', ip: '10.14.101.52', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_67'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My best guess is that the browser window is closing, but the screenshot hasn't been taken yet, so when it tries to take the screenshot, it says "eh, I can't even access the tab" and blows up in your face.

One step in the right direction is to wrap your screenshot taking code in a try/catch and log any errors from that into your test log (simply so you aren't completely eating the exception).  Then the actual exception from the failed test will be in the stack trace (because it shouldn't get caught).

Comment: This is exactly what was happening. Thanks for your answer. Wrapping the screenshot in a try/catch is an excellent idea as well.

Comment: Hi, Can you please write the specific code you did in order to solve this issue? thanks @Conner